# $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Why $S_4$ is not isomorphic to $D_{12}$? where $S_4$ is symmetric group and $D_{12}$ is dihedral group of order $12$.here number of element are same $S_4$ has $4!=24$ elements and $D_{12}$ has also $2n$ means $12(2)=24$ elements. but i can't find that property which holds in one of this group but another doesn't has that property.please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $S_4$ has no element of order $12$ in it, whereas $D_{12}$ has.

Comment: how can i justify this thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can an element in $S_4$ have order 12? Can you think of an element in $D_{12}$ or order 12? What can you conclude?

Comment: ya i got this hint from my teacher but how can i conclude that thing bcz there are 24 permutation and in $D_{12}$ there are 12 rotation and many daigonals so what is the short justification?

Comment: Is there another property which holds in $S_4$ but not in $D_{12}$?

Comment: Can u give me an element of $D_{12}$ which has order 12?

Comment: ... do you know the definition of $D_n$?

Comment: i like both the answers...

Comment: here i got an element (1 2 3.....12) element of $D_{12}$ but i can't get an element of order 12 in $S_4$ maximum order of element of $S_4$ is 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know some basic stuff about the symmetric and dihedral groups (or else you can try to prove them: it's fun) , you can try the following approach:

For $\,2<n\in\Bbb N\,$ :

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\text{ If}\;\;D_n=\langle\,a\,,\,b\;;\;a^2=b^n=1\;,\;aba=b^{n-1}=b^{-1}\rangle,\;\text{then for even}\,\,n\;\;Z(D_n)=\{1\,,\,b^{n/2}\}\\{}\\(2)&Z(S_n)=\{1\}\end{align*}$$

From the above it follows at once that $\,S_4\ncong D_{12}\,$

Comment: can u tell me which property is break here?

Comment: The groups don't have isomorphic centers...what else?

Comment: i like both the answers...

Answer (score 1):

For even $n$, the abelianization of $D_n = \langle r,s : r^n = s^2 = (rs)^2 = 1 \rangle$ is $\langle r,s : rs=sr, r^2=s^2 = 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, but the abelianization of $S_m$ is always $\mathbb{Z}/2$ for $m>1$.

Comment: if u explain me i will try to understand this definition.

Comment: Can i say that $S_4$ is not Abelian but $D_{12}$ is abelian?

Comment: $D_{12}$ is not abelian.